# copying files from subfolder to relative path

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I am trying to copy all folders and files from a subfolder to relative path.

Is there a way to do with one command?

```
cp askubuntu/assets/ assets/
cp askubuntu/index.html index.html
cp askubuntu/sponsor    sponsor/
cp askubuntu/provider provider/

rm askubuntu/ -R
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mv askubuntu/* .
```

`mv` is the move command vary similar to `cp` copy command except it removes file at same time. It's actually more efficient because the file isn't actually copied and removed but rather renamed.

`.` is shorthand for current directory ie `/home/my_username/`

Comment: this says 'mv: cannot move 'askubuntu/assets' to './assets': Directory not empty

Comment: I've shortened command removing -v switch

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. It leaves an empty directory still but already better than my approach. thanks